# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Place was called on a node which was placed already in newest version of compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
`import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    var spanNumber by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
            Button(onClick = { spanNumber = !spanNumber}) {
                Text(text = "Change mode")
            }
        }
        repeat(list.size) {
            item(span = { GridItemSpan(currentLineSpan =
            if (spanNumber) {
                2
            } else {
                1
            }
            ) }) {
                Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                    Text(text = "Hello $it", modifier = Modifier
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .padding(horizontal = 4.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

When I change spanNumber to change view mode, if change from spanNumber = 2 to 1 and scroll the app will crash with exception:
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17202
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Place was called on a node which was placed already
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:941)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer-aW-9-wM(Placeable.kt:471)
...
`